# solution of system of coupled partial differential equations

Tags: maple, differential-equations

I have following system of coupled Partial differential equations.
How can I solve the system by Maple?
\begin{align}   m_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t^2}+A_1\frac{\partial ^4u_1(x,t)}{\partial x^4}+k(u_1-u_2)=F_1(t) \delta(x-x_1),  \end{align}
\begin{align}    m_2\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial t^2}-A_2\frac{\partial ^2u_2(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+k(u_2-u_1)=F_2(t)\delta(x-x_2).  \end{align}
**Code:**

```
PDE1:=m1*diff(u1(x,t),t$2)+A1*diff(u1(x,t),x$4)+k*(u1(x,t)-u2(x,t))=F1(t)*delta(x-x1);
PDE2:=m2*diff(u2(x,t),t$2)-A2*diff(u2(x,t),x$2)+k*(u2(x,t)-u1(x,t))=F2(t)*delta(x-x2);
```

In here,  $A_i, m_i, x_i$ and $k$ are constants where $i=1,2$ and $\delta$ is Dirac Delta function.

**Boundary conditions:**

$u_1(0,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(0,t)=u_1(l,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(l,t)=0$,

$u_2(0,t)=u_2(l,t)=0$

**Initial conditions:**

$u_i(x,0)=w_{i0}(x),$

$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x}(x,0)=y_{i0}(x)$ for $i=1,2.$

Since $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ are unspecified (ungiven) functions, solutions $u_1,u_2$ which we seek will be depended on  $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$.

Comment: Can you write down the equations that you are trying to solve in mathematical notation instead of Maple syntax?

Comment: You can add that to your question

Comment: \begin{align}
  m_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t^2}+A_1\frac{\partial ^2u_1(x,t)}{\partial x^4}+k(u_1-u_2)=F_1(t) \delta(x-x_1),
 \end{align}
 \begin{align}
   m_2\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial t^2}-A_2\frac{\partial ^2u_2(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+k(u_2-u_1)=F_2(t)\delta(x-x_2).
 \end{align}

Comment: Second term, is that a fourth or second derivative? Either way, have you tried the simple finite central difference discretization to get a fully implicit equation in time and solve the linear problem? That's clearly the first approach. No idea about stability or how the errors work for this equation though.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Maple can find a closed solution for this system, so your only option looks like a numerical solution (for which Maple is completely unsuited, and you should use Matlab (or Numpy, or Julia, or a numerical programming environment of your choice) instead. But this would be a different question (which you're welcome to ask!)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `delta()` with Maple synax for the Dirac delta: `Dirac()` Maple's pdsolve given an error. But, not doing the replacement, it seems to make a little progress maybe:

```
pdsolve({PDE1, PDE2}, {u1(x, t), u2(x, t)});
```

Once I add the boundary conditions it stops making any progress though (and the same result if I replace your `delta` with `Diract`).  It just returns NULL.

```
pdsolve({PDE1, PDE2, u1(0, t) = 0, u1(1, t) = 0, u2(0, t) = 0, u2(1, t) = 0, 
         (D[2](u1))(0, t) = 0, (D[2](u1))(1, t) = 0}, {u1(x, t), u2(x, t)})
```

I suspect that you have too many symbolic constants and unknown functions for pdsolve to handle.  There may be other tricks you can play with options the pdsolve function, but its documentation is pretty impenetrable.